# update observable object from array in observable object

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable, switchmap

I have documents id in the Information I am getting from service. I need documents Info to be attached to this parent information and return parent. Not able to return observables in loop.

The second switch map is working fine. The first is not executing if I return tInfo from map, it gives following error below.

> Argument of type '(tInfo: {        documents;        documentsInfo:
> any[];    }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value:
> { documents: any; documentsInfo: any[]; }, index: number) =>
> ObservableInput'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type
> 'ObservableInput'

```
public transform(tId: any,name: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
  return this.sService.getTaxById(tId).pipe(
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
    switchMap((tInfo:{ documents ; documentsInfo: any [] }) => {
      if (tInfo.documents) {
        tInfo..documents.forEach(doc => {
          return this.sService
            .getFiles(doc.docId).pipe(
              map((filesInfo: { FileName: ''; downloadUrl: '' }) => {
                        const fileObjnew =
                          {
                            docName: filesInfo.FileName,
                            downloadUrl: filesInfo.downloadUrl,
                          }
                          tInfo.documentsInfo.push(fileObjnew);
                      })
            );
        });
       return of(taxInfo);
      }
    }),
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
    switchMap((Info: { cc: '' ; authority: '' ; cName: ''}) => {
      if (Info.authority) {
        const cc = taxInfo.cc;
        return this.sService.getOrgs(cc).pipe(
          map((orgsData: any) => {
            console.log("Data============>", orgsData);
            (orgsData || []).forEach(tax => {
              if (orgsData.aid === tax.id) {
                Info.cName = tax.parentName;
              }
            });
            return Info;
          })
        );
      }
    }),
    map((Info) => {
      if (name === 'subsTemplate') {
        return this.subsTemplate(Info);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: You can subscribe to your observable to access it's value and assign it

Comment: Nope Subscribe is not executing for getFiles service

Comment: you need to have return statements outside of the if-satements as well in `switchMap`.

Comment: There seems to be some other general problems with the code you posted. Such as two dots in `tInfo..documents.forEach` and the usage of `taxInfo` which I suppose should be ?`tInfo`. Can you make sure to post the same code that you have tried?

Comment: But the main semantical issue with your code is that the `.getFiles(...)...` observable is never subscribed to. Instead of using `forEach`, you should `.map` which will result in an array of observables. You can then use `forkJoin` to join them into one observable that you can use in the return statement of `switchMap`

Answer (score 1):

In the first `switchMap` you have to return an observable in all code paths and to chain the `getFiles` sub-observables to your main observable, then return the observable combined by `forkJoin`.

You can try the following:

```js
public transform(tId: any, name: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
  return this.sService.getTaxById(tId).pipe(
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
    switchMap((tInfo: { documents; documentsInfo: any[] }) => {
      if (tInfo.documents) {
        return forkJoin(
          tInfo.documents.map((doc) =>
            this.sService.getFiles(doc.docId).pipe(
              map((filesInfo: { FileName: ''; downloadUrl: '' }) => {
                const fileObjnew = {
                  docName: filesInfo.FileName,
                  downloadUrl: filesInfo.downloadUrl,
                };
                tInfo.documentsInfo.push(fileObjnew);
              })
            )
          )
        ).pipe(mapTo(taxInfo));
      }
      return of(taxInfo);
    }),
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
    switchMap((Info: { cc: ''; authority: ''; cName: '' }) => {
      if (Info.authority) {
        const cc = taxInfo.cc;
        return this.sService.getOrgs(cc).pipe(
          map((orgsData: any) => {
            console.log('Data============>', orgsData);
            (orgsData || []).forEach((tax) => {
              if (orgsData.aid === tax.id) {
                Info.cName = tax.parentName;
              }
            });
            return Info;
          })
        );
      }
      return of(null);
    }),
    map((Info) => {
      if (name === 'subsTemplate') {
        return this.subsTemplate(Info);
      }
    })
  );
}
```